# List of installed packages on gentoo with all use flags

Tags: gentoo

What is the trick or possibility to get the list of all my installed packages on gentoo with indication of all used/unused use-flags, versions, etc?

Something similar what you see with when run emerge for update, but is there an option to see the what I have already installed in same format as emerge showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that

> emerge -pve world

is what you need.

The output of the command looks like
[image: output of emerge -pve world]

Comment: For first sight looks pretty close!